# which is the proper use capital letters after a comma

Tags: commas

Which of these two sentences is the proper way to write. Hi betty, thank you or Hi Betty, Thank you

Comment: Neither is correctly capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is written incorrectly because the first letter of the names of people must be capitalized in a sentence.

The second option is written incorrectly because it is incorrect to capitalize the first letter of a word after a comma without reason. By default, they are left uncapitalized.

The following sentence's structure would work.

Hi Betty, thank you [for blah blah blah].